# Sorting on json properties function works, but how to define it with strong type checking turned on?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a json structure from a service with .attributes json values. The micro service returns this type of structure, so at times I need to sort on id from the DTO and then other times sort via several attributes from the IContactsAttributes.

```
export interface IContactsDto {
  _links: ILink,
  attributes: IContactAttributes,
  id: number,
  lastUpdated: Date;
  createdOn: Date;
  localCreatedOn: Date;
  whoUpdated: number;
  location_id: number;
}

export interface IContactAttributes {
  contactIsAdmin: boolean;
  contactIsOperations: boolean;
  contactIsMarketing: boolean;
  contactLastName: string;
  contactFirstName: string;
  contactTitle: string;
  contactEmail: string;
  contactPhone: string;
}
```

This works, but when I move this function to a library with strong type checking on, I get:

Error: src/app/microServices/dictionariesService.ts:102:32 - error TS2345: Argument of type '0 | ((a: any, b: any) => 0 | 1 | -1)' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: any, b: any) => number'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type '(a: any, b: any) => number'.

102     return super.getAll().sort(this.sortService.sortCompareAscending('id', false, IJsonTypes.isNumber));
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
getAllSortedByInterfaceName() {
    return super.getAll().sort(this.sortService.sortCompareAscending('contactsLastName', true, IJsonTypes.isString));
  }
```

Compare Function:

```
sortCompareAscending(prop, isAttribute, jsonType: IJsonTypes) {
    switch (jsonType) {
      case IJsonTypes.isString:
        if (!isAttribute) {
          return function(a, b) {
            if (a[prop].toLowerCase() < b[prop].toLowerCase()) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (a[prop].toLowerCase() > b[prop].toLowerCase()) {
              return 1;
            }
            return 0;
          };
        } else {
          return function(a, b) {
            if (a.attributes[prop].toLowerCase() < b.attributes[prop].toLowerCase()) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (a.attributes[prop].toLowerCase() > b.attributes[prop].toLowerCase()) {
              return 1;
            }
            return 0;
          };
        }

      case IJsonTypes.isNumber:
        if (!isAttribute) {
          return function(a, b) {
            if (a[prop] < b[prop]) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {
              return 1;
            }
            return 0;
          };
        } else {
          return function(a, b) {
            if (a.attributes[prop] < b.attributes[prop]) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (a.attributes[prop] > b.attributes[prop]) {
              return 1;
            }
            return 0;
          };
        }
      case IJsonTypes.isBoolean:
        if (!isAttribute) {
          return function(a, b) {
            return (a[prop] === b[prop])? 0: a[prop]? -1: 1;
          };
        } else {
          return function(a, b) {
            return (a.attributes[prop] === b.attributes[prop])? 0: a.attributes[prop]? -1: 1;
          };
        }
      case IJsonTypes.isDate:
        this.logger.warn("IJsonTypes.isDate", "NOT IMPLEMENTED");
        break;
    }
  }
```

Intellij wants it to look like this:

```
return function(a: { [x: string]: { toLowerCase: () => number; }; }, b: { [x: string]: { toLowerCase: () => number; }; }) {
```

and I tried that, but it still the same error.  So, I'm unclear on how to define sortCompare with strong type checking on?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is always right, I guess - just in case someone else needs this:

I had a switch statement for json types.  Even though the code could never fall through, the compiler (strong type) didn't like just return 0 - which makes sense... sort of

```
return function (a: any, b: any) {
          return 0;
        }
```